# Contact form onChange function call error

Tags: reactjs

I am working on creating a contact form using react.js and I get below error;
 'ContactForm Component should call onChanges with updated contact data when email field is changed.' Any help?!

I get this error in contact.jsx file. Not sure about how to fix this issue.

rextester link: https://rextester.com/LWKDFE70058

I know the fix is to add 'this.props.name.onChange(this.props.data)' line but not sure where to add it. Any help will be greatly appreciated?!

Comment: `propTypes` is for the parent component not child, means this props must be passed from the parent. If you are working on the component that do not have a parent dependency (passing props from parent) you do not need to declare that. inshort this telling you, if you want to use component then you need to pass this properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your input fields to a data model object. And also when the input fields value changes then need to set the new value back to the object model.

For eg. have a look at the below sample code:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```